# Transpose data using sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have following data in a table

```
+---------+-----+----------+
| Zip_ cd | id  | assignmt.|
|---------+-----+----------+
| 1812    | 777 | S        |
| 1812    | 111 | P        |
| 1451    | 878 | S        | 
| 55      | 45  | x        |  
| 55      | 646 | T        |
| 55      | 455 | Z        |
+---------+-----+----------+
```

I want to transpose it as following

```
+---------+-----+----+---------+-----+----------+---------+-----+----------+
| Zip_ cd | id  | ass| Zip_cd1 | id1 |assignmt1 | Zip_cd2 | id2 |assignmt3 |
+---------+-----+----+---------+-----+----------+---------+-----+----------+
| 1812    | 777 | S  | 1812    | 111 | P        | 1812    | 111 | P        |
| 1451    | 878 | S  |         |     |          |         |     |          |  
| 55      | 45  | X  | 55      | 646 | T        |  55     | 455 | Z        |
+---------+-----+----------+---------+----------+---------+-----+----------+
```

So, I basically want to transpose based on the zip code.  If 2 rows have same zip code its needs to be in single row.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the data you get from this query? Your request means that you will need a variable number of columns, which is not really the easiest way (I actually don't know how to construct a query like this if it's even possible)

Answer (score 0):

Another query using pivot functionality:

```
select *
  from table_name
  pivot ( max(id) id
        , max(assignmt) assignmt
    FOR assignmt IN ('S' S,
                     'P' P));

+---------+-------+------------+--------+------------+
| ZIP_ CD | S_ID  | S_ASSIGNMT.| P_ID   | P_ASSIGNMT.|
+---------+-------+------------+--------+------------+
| 1812    | 777   | S          | 111    | P          |
| 1451    | 878   | S          | NULL   | NULL       |
+---------+-------+------------+--------+------------+
```